# If $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets of the set of real numbers, then is $A+B$ closed?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be two closed subsets of the set of real numbers.

Define $A+B=\{a+b\in\mathbb{R}:a\in A ,b\in B\}$.

Is it true that $A+B$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$?

If not, could you give a counter-example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is not true. Take $A=\{\pi+n+1\colon n\in\mathbb N\}$, and $ B=\left \{-n-1+\frac1 {n+2}\colon n\in \mathbb N\right\} $. Both sets are closed, $\pi $ is a limit point of their sum, but is not on their sum.

If both $ A, B $ are compact, so is their sum (Since $ A+B $ is the image of $ A\times B $ under the continuous function $(x, y)\mapsto x+y $). Can you see what happens when one set is compact and the other isn't?

Comment: May I ask why you used "$n+1$" in the argument of the set $A$ and "$-n-1$" in the argument of the set $B$?

Comment: (To see how one could find the counterexample, think about the obvious approach: If $ x $ is a limit point of the sum, there are $ a_n\in A $ and $ b_n\in B $ with $ a_n+ b_n\to x $. If the sets are bounded, both sequences have subsequences that converge to points whose sum converges to $ x $. The issue is then if the sequences are unbounded and yet $ a_n+b_n $ somehow manages to converge.)

Comment: @Yk26 It is not strictly needed, simply to avoid having to decide what happens if we allow $ n=0$.

Comment: (Typo in the comment: whose sum *is*.)

Answer (score 14):

Let $A$ be the set of negative integers.

Let $B$ be the set of all $n+\frac{1}{2^n}$ where $n$ ranges over the positive integers.

Then $A$ and $B$ are closed.

But $A+B$ is not closed, since it contains numbers arbitrarily close to $0$ but does not contain $0$.