# Sum of Closed Subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

If $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}$ are closed in $\mathbb{R}$, is $A+B$ also closed in $\mathbb{R}$? I think it is not, but could not find a counter example: any suggestions?

Comment: By $A+B$, do you mean $\{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124130/sum-of-two-closed-sets-in-mathbb-r-is-closed/124133).

Comment: Relevant threads: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906440/if-a-and-b-are-closed-subsets-of-the-set-of-real-numbers-then-is-ab-clos) [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422756/ab-is-closed-if-one-of-them-is-compact) [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267776/give-an-example-of-two-closed-sets-a-b-subseteq-mathbbr-such-that-the-set?lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $A= \bf Z$ and $B= \sqrt 2 \bf Z$,(of course as a subspace of $\bf R$ with usual topology) ?

**Extra Exercise:**  If $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed then $A+B$ is closed.

Comment: what isyour set B??

Comment: Integral Multiples of $\sqrt 2$ !